# Weak enrichment and bicategories

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, enriched-category-theory, 2-categories

I'm trying to find examples where the following perspective on bicategories is developed.

We can define a 2-category as being enriched in Cat, where Cat is treated as a monoidal category using the Cartesian product. It seems like you can treat a bicategory as a weak enrichment, where the necessary associativity diagrams are weakened and replaced with the associator and unitor 2-cells.

This seems to make certain things much simpler, particularly if you wanted to work with a bicategory whose hom-categories were categories with structure and the composition and coherent 2-cells were to respect that structure. That also makes me think that something goes wrong when you take this approach, because I can't seem to find any references where this is developed.

Comment: This may seem like self-promotion, but: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Trimble+n-category

Answer (score 5):

It is difficult to axiomatize a "weak enrichment" in general. You have an enrichment base $\mathcal V$, hom-objects $C(a,b)\in \mathcal V$, a composition morphism $C(b,c)\otimes C(a,b)\to C(a,c)$ in $\mathcal V$, then an associator isomorphism in $\mathcal V$...So $\mathcal V$ must be a 2-category! In fact this line of thought can be pushed through, see [here.](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+bicategory) But such a $C$ is certainly no easier to define than a plain bicategory, any more than an enriched category is easier to define than a category. The weakness of the enrichment forces us to abandon the dimensional drop, in which an $n$-category is a category enriched in $n-1$-categories, and in particular makes this approach unmanageably complex for higher dimensions.

Comment: One solution to this problem is to use $(∞,1)$-categories, which can be defined on their own and where weak enrichment is a perfectly reasonable concept (nay, the only version of enrichment you can talk about!). Indeed, I believe bicategories are just categories enriched in the $(2,1)$-category of 1-categories, and you can easily extend the process to define $(n,n)$-categories as categories enriched in the $(∞,1)$-category of $(n-1,n-1)$-categories

Comment: @DenisNardin Of course. I wonder whether anybody has ever actually written your result down, by the way; people don't seem to be entirely ready to abandon the traditional presentation of bicategories.

Comment: @KevinCarlson It depends on what the meaning of "categories enriched in the (2,1)-category of 1-categories" is. A number of equivalences between bicategories and various models for "weak (2,2)-categories" have been proved. (And of course, as I'm sure you'll agree, there is no need to abandon the traditional presentation of bicategories.)

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell Yes, that was definitely tongue-in-cheek. Since you're here, do you happen to have a reference for an equivalence with a fully non-algebraic model?

Comment: @KevinCarlson In Lack & Paoli's paper [2-nerves for bicategores](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607271) they prove a biequivalence between 2-categories of bicategories and Tamsamani's 2-categories (i.e. Cat-enriched Segal categories). In my draft paper [A homotopy coherent cellular nerve for bicategories](http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~alexc/coherentnerve.pdf), I prove (among other things) Quillen equivalences between Lack's model category of bicategories, a Bousfield localisation of Ara's model structure for 2-quasi-categories, and Rezk's model structure for (2,2)-$\Theta$-spaces.

Comment: I think your comment about "abandon the dimensional drop" is phrased confusingly.  It's still true that an $n$-category is a category enriched in $(n-1)$-categories, it's just that we have to consider the *collection* of $(n-1)$-categories as itself forming an $n$-category, or at least an $(n,1)$-category as Denis points out.

Comment: I'm also not quite sure what you mean by "difficult to define a weak enrichment".  Defining an enriched bicategory is totally straightforward, and does indeed make things much easier when you want to talk about bicategories whose hom-categories have extra structure.  Moreover, an ordinary bicategory is a bicategory weakly enriched over the *strict* 2-category Cat, so you don't actually need to have already defined an ordinary bicategory is before defining an enriched one.

Comment: It's true that things get subtler in higher dimensions, as always, but the OP only asked about $n=2$.

Comment: @MikeShulman Yeah, by "in general" I guess I was thinking of higher dimensions, which is indeed not really relevant here. I agree that I didn't clearly phrase the dimensional drop thing, but your point is what I was trying to get at. Or in another way, I think it's strictly easier to define a 2-category as a category enriched in the monoidal category of categories rather than directly, but the definitions of a bicategory directly or respectively as a bicategory enriched in the bicategory of categories are identical.

Comment: No, I think it's equally possible to define a bicategory in an explicit way with a collection of 0-cells, a collection of 1-cells, a collection of 2-cells, with various operations satisfying various axioms, without mentioning any hom-categories off the bat.

Comment: @MikeShulman Sure, if you like.